# Perform a series of mutations to columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to replace some text in my dataframe (a few rows given below)

```
> dput(Henry.longer[1:4,])
structure(list(N_l = c(4, 4, 4, 4), UG = c("100", "100", "100", 
"100"), S = c(12, 12, 12, 12), Sample = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), EQ = c("Henry", 
"Henry", "Henry", "Henry"), DF = c(0.798545454545455, 0.798545454545455, 
0.798545454545455, 0.798545454545455), meow = c("Henry.Exterior.single", 
"Multi", "Henry.Exterior.multi", "Henry.Interior.single"), Girder =     c("Henry.Exterior.single", 
"Henry.Interior.multi", "Henry.Exterior.multi", "Interior")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(UG = "100", S = 12, .rows = list(
1:4)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I try to mutate the dataframe as:

```
Henry.longer <- Henry.longer %>% 
  mutate(Loading = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Exterior.single", "Single")) %>%
  mutate(Loading = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Exterior.multi", "Multi")) %>%
  mutate(Loading = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Interior.single", "Single")) %>%
  mutate(Loading = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Interior.multi", "Multi")) %>%
  mutate(Girder = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Exterior.multi", "Exterior")) %>%
  mutate(Girder = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Exterior.single", "Exterior")) %>%
  mutate(Girder = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Interior.multi", "Interior")) %>%
  mutate(Girder = str_replace(meow, "Henry.Interior.single", "Interior")) %>%
  select(-meow)
```

But for some reason the results does not get applied to all the rows and only:

```
      N_l UG        S Sample EQ       DF Loading               Girder               
1     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Henry.Exterior.single Henry.Exterior.single
2     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Multi                 Henry.Interior.multi 
3     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Henry.Exterior.multi  Henry.Exterior.multi 
4     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Henry.Interior.single Interior
```

Comment: Where exactly is `meow` defined? (Perhaps you intended instead to give the output from `dput(Henry.longer[1:4,])`?)

Comment: It looks like you posted *all* the rows, but only a few columns (i.e. 1:4). Maybe `dput(head(Henry.longer))` will do the trick?

Comment: yea sorry just fixed that hah! @r2evans

Comment: yea sorry just fixed that hah @Dubukay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can use lookup vectors for this, if it's easy or safer to use static string lookups:

```r
tr_vec <- c(Henry.Exterior.single = "Single", Henry.Exterior.multi = "Multi", Henry.Interior.single = "Single", Henry.Interior.multi = "Multi")
tr_vec2 <- c(Henry.Exterior.multi = "Exterior", Henry.Exterior.single = "Exterior", Henry.Interior.multi = "Interior", Henry.Interior.single = "Interior")
Henry.longer %>%
  mutate(
    Loading = coalesce(tr_vec[Loading], Loading),
    Girder = coalesce(tr_vec2[Girder], Girder)
  )
# # A tibble: 4 x 8
# # Groups:   UG, S [1]
#     N_l UG        S Sample EQ       DF Loading Girder  
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
# 1     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Single  Exterior
# 2     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Multi   Interior
# 3     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Multi   Exterior
# 4     4 100      12 NA     Henry 0.799 Single  Interior
```

The advantage of RonakShah's regex solution is that it can very easily handle many of the types of substrings you appear to need. Regexes do carry a little risk, though, in that they *may* (unlikely in that answer, but) miss match.

Comment: So i want the `Girder` Column  to show the `Exterior` or `Interior` values and the `Loading` to show the `Single` and `Multi`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `str_replace` I guess it would be easier to extract what you want using regex.

```
library(dplyr)

Henry.longer %>%
  mutate(Loading = sub('.*\\.', '', meow), 
         Girder = sub('.*\\.(\\w+)\\..*', '\\1', meow))
```

where

`Loading`  - removes everything until last dot

`Girder`   - extracts a word between two dots.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it is still hard for me to understand regex enough to produce this, but I see what you did here!!

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, looks like you've got some answers here already but here's a super-simple one that uses `stringr::str_extract`:

```r
Henry.longer <- Henry.longer %>%
  mutate(Loading = str_extract(meow, "single|multi")) %>%
  mutate(Girder = str_extract(meow, "Interior|Exterior"))
```

It's worth noting that the demo data has a weird entry for `meow` in one column, so it didn't run perfectly on my machine:

[image: output]